# Kaggle Beginner problems

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, kaggle

I am looking for beginner Machine Learning Linear Regression problems. I searched in Kaggle, but couldn't find a proper one. Can you please suggest me a beginner problem from Kaggle, or from any other platform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kaggle has tons of linear regression notebooks and datasets to learn from, most popular ones are probably about house pricing (given certain house features predict it's price).

Here's a new one I'm looking forward to solve:

[Ben & Jerry's flavours and ratings](https://www.kaggle.com/tysonpo/ice-cream-dataset) ---> `products.csv`

The main goal would be predict wich ice cream flavours are better accepted based on it's ingredients.